# Why are extra 92 pixel square thumbnails created?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

Disabling this WordPress feature which automatically generates various sizes of an uploaded image, is normally as simple as going to **WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Media** screen and changing all image-size options to `0` (zero).

Unless I am missing something, this is not the case with my blog. Any image I upload gets a 92 pixel square thumbnail cousin.

I have searched through all the theme files for any and all occurrences of the number '92', but there's none! So I am guessing it's WordPress core?

**PS:**

- [This WordPress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) says that the default sizes for thumbnail, medium, and large resolution images are 150 px, 300 px, and 640 px (squares) respectively. A 92 px square is clearly not among the defaults.
- I read [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-stop-extra-thumbnail-generation-by-wordpress) that WordPress creates *"one additional thumb for Dashboard interface needs"*. I am not sure where. Is this why the 92px thumb is being generated? (I don't think so.)
- In case it helps, I am using a WordPress.com theme called "[Reddle](https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/reddle/)" on my self-hosted blog. It looks like the theme was developed by Automattic Theme Wranglers.

Comment: Did you check the `functions.php` file? Check something like `set_post_thumbnail_size` function... anyway if you make changes, keep in mind that you need upload the image again, to generate the new thumbnail and note changes

Comment: @Tom I use a Gedit (text editor) plugin to search all my theme files -- absolutely no instances of `92`, the number. I use this in my functions.php though `add_image_size( 'featimage', 310, 150, true );` to define a custom image size. But it shouldn't be messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the output of [`get_intermediate_image_sizes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes). If there are any image sizes listed other than `'thumbnail'`, `'medium'` or `'large'`, a plugin or a theme has added a custom size.

From our chat discussion I know it was *WPtouch Pro*. :) But it could have been any plugin. There are also sometimes plugins in the directory `mu-plugins`.